# how to add administrators and managers entries into database for cakePHP 2x ACL aros and acos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, cakephp-2.x

I'm implementing ACL in a CakePHP app that I have and I seem to be struggling with setting up ACOs. I've been following the Simple ACL Controlled Application
[https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html] tutorial and I've set up the aros, acos and aros_acos tables using sql file. 
In the documentation they said insert user,manager,group by browsing a website. Problem is when i browse for that website no such document was found there like bellow.[image]

http://http://example.com/groups/add

Now how can i add users and administrators into database for aros and acos table using cake bake or SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake by me. Just need to use

```
localhost/project_name/users/add
```